# Reverse select binding - possible?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-bindings

I have a case that requires an object property's sub-property to be bound automatically to some defined property, but unbind old and rebind new on any change in the parent property; namely *reverse select binding*.

For illustration only (my case is different but far too complex to explain here) say i have a label that you are allowed to change for different size/color/font etc. but the text should remain the same:

```
StringProperty text;
ObjectProperty<Label> label;

Bindings.select(label, "text").bind(text);
```

Of course this is illegal since binding is possible on properties only.

Except of explicitly listen for changes, is there an out-of-the-box solution for this?

Comment: I would think a listener would be the easiest way to do this

Comment: @James_D Clear response from the JavaFX expert. Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution that involves binding?

Comment: Nothing so far, but maybe try [ReactFX](https://github.com/TomasMikula/ReactFX), maybe they have a way doing it, not sure.